# Will this get the element by tag name "c" ? in my program it is not working?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>1</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>2</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
        <c type="h">
            <d>v</d>
            <f>d</f>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dBFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dB = dBFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dB.parse(url);     
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("b").item(0).getChildNodes();
```

Can I say

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("c").item(0).getchildnode() ;
```

Will this get the element by tag name "c"? In my program it is not working. Can someone help?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which element or node do you want to get?

Comment: I don't know whether `doc.getElementsByTagName("c")` would return all `c` tags (I'd guess so) but if so, `.getChildNodes()` (not `.getchildnode()`) would then return the `d` and `f` tags, wouldn't it? Thus, leaving that out might provides the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I say
>
> ```
> doc.getElementsByTagName("c").item(0).getchildnode() ;
> ```

**Here is a short and simple XPath expression** that selects the child elements of the first `c` element in an XML document:

```
(//c)[1]/*
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="(//c)[1]/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>1</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
        <c type="lol">
            <d>2</d>
            <f>2</f>
        </c>
        <c type="h">
            <d>v</d>
            <f>d</f>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

**we get the wanted, correct result -- the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output**:

```
<d>1</d>
<f>2</f>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("c").item(0).getchildnodes();
```

then you have node list that contains the elements:

```
<d>1</d>
<f>2</f>
```

(the child nodes of the first `<c>` element in your document)

Comment: I am not gettting this result ... :(

Comment: double-check that you (a) read the correct document, (b) spell the tagname correctly (casesensitive!) and (c) the element doesn't have a namespace (like in the simplified example). It *should* work.